# Using xsl to create localized content part 2

Tags: xml, xslt, localization

A slightly different requirement to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326974/using-xsl-to-create-localized-content)

The dictionary stays the same format but grows:

```
<resources>
    <text name="property.to.match">
        <en_US>The American translation</en_US>
        <en_GB>The British translation</en_GB>
        <en>The language localized, but non locale based generic translation</en>
    </text>
    <text name="other.property.to.match">
        <en>The other language localized, but non locale based generic translation</en>
    </text
    <text name="another.property.to.match">
        <en>Second generic property</en>
    </text>
    <text name="a.label.to.match">
        <en>Generic Checkbox label</en>
    </text>
    <text name="some.text.to.translate">
        <en>This text follows a static bit of text</en>
    </text>
</resources>
```

But the document in which I would like to match is more complex:

```
<html>
    <div>Lot's of html</div>
    <div>[property.to.match]</div>
    <div>
        <h1>[other.property.to.match]</h1>
        <p><img src="x.jpg" />[another.property.to.match]</p>
        <input type="checkbox"/>[a.label.to.match]
        <p>Some text that shouldn't be translated followed by [some.text.to.translate]
    </div>
</html>
```

So the matcher needs to be able to find multiple text strings within the */text() that start and end with [] but could be in amongst other nodes and bits of untrnaslated text.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:param name="pLookupPath" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/lookup2.xml'"/>
     <xsl:param name="pLang" select="'en_GB'"/>

     <xsl:key name="kLookup" match="text/*"
      use="concat(../@name, '+', name())"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vDict" select="document($pLookupPath)"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="replaceWithLookup" match=
      "text()[contains(., '[') and contains(., ']')]">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
          <xsl:value-of select=
           "substring-before(concat($pText, '['), '[')"/>

          <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
           "substring-before(substring-after($pText, '['), ']')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vReplacement">
         <xsl:for-each select="$vDict">
          <xsl:value-of select=
          "(key('kLookup', concat($vToken, '+', $pLang))
         |
           key('kLookup', concat($vToken, '+', substring-before($pLang, '_')))
           )[1]"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$vReplacement">
          <xsl:value-of select="$vReplacement"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$vToken">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $vToken, ']')"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select=
            "substring-after
              ($pText,
               substring-before(concat($pText, '['), '[')
               )"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:if test="$vToken">
         <xsl:call-template name="replaceWithLookup">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
            "substring-after($pText, concat('[', $vToken, ']'))"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one but made more difficult and challenging -- the last text nodes contains two replacement targets):

```
<html>
    <div>Lot's of html</div>
    <div>[property.to.match]</div>
    <div>
        <h1>[other.property.to.match]</h1>
        <p>
            <img src="x.jpg" />[another.property.to.match]
        </p>
        <input type="checkbox"/>[a.label.to.match]         
        <p>Some text that shouldn't be translated followed
        by [some.text.to.translate]
        XXX [other.property.to.match]
        </p>
    </div>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html>
   <div>Lot's of html</div>
   <div>The British translation</div>
   <div>
      <h1>The other language localized, but non locale based generic translation</h1>
      <p><img src="x.jpg">Second generic property
      </p><input type="checkbox">Generic Checkbox label
      <p>Some text that shouldn't be translated followed
                by This text follows a static bit of text
                XXX The other language localized, but non locale based generic translation

      </p>
   </div>
</html>
```